# What is the best way to modify a [UInt8] byte array in swift 4?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, uint8array

Hi I know many of you already know how it can be done but please help me as I'm a beginner to swift programming.

Please consider this code and help me with changes,

//My read code

```
let ReceiveData = rxCharacteristic?.value
        if let ReceiveData = ReceiveData {
            let ReceivedNoOfBytes = ReceiveData.count
            myByteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
            (ReceiveData as NSData).getBytes(&myByteArray, length: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
            print("Data Received ",myByteArray)
               }
```

//Now I'm storing them into some local variables like below

```
let b0 = myByteArray[0]
let b0 = myByteArray[1]
let b2 = myByteArray[2]
let b3 = myByteArray[3]
```

//Now I  want to insert some data which are coming from a Textbox

```
var tb1 = textbox1.text
var b1 = tb1.flatMap{UInt8(String($0))}

var tb2 = textbox2.text
var b2 = tb2.flatMap{UInt8(String($0))}
```

//Now I'm writing all data using a function block like below

```
let Transmitdata = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
                peripheral.writeValue(Transmitdata as Data, for: txCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
                print("Data Sent",Transmitdata)
```

Here I'm currently creating a new byte array under class declaration and assigning the received byte array. Like below

```
class Example:UIViwecontroller{

var storebytes: [UInt8]()


func somefunc(){

storebytes = myByteArray

}
```

And then try swapping my textbox data in the place of the first two positions in myByteArray and then pass it to transmitdata.

Is there any simple way of doing it? Like just insert bytes in places I need and then pass it to the transmit?

I have tried using some method like

```
bytes.insert(new data,at: index)
```

but it gives me an index out of range. Does someone know a better method how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3+ `Data` can be used as a collection type containing `UInt8` objects.

Having a `Data` object from a `String`

```
let hello = Data("hello".utf8)
```

you can convert it to `[UInt8]` simply with

```
let hello1 = [UInt8](hello)
```

and back to `Data`

```
let hello2 = Data(hello1)
```

`Data` provides all manipulation API like `append`, `insert`, `remove`

---

Actually you don't need `[UInt8]`. Given two strings as `Data` objects

```
var hello = Data("Hello !".utf8)
let world = Data("world".utf8)
```

You can insert `world` in `hello`

```
hello.insert(contentsOf: world, at: 6)
print(String(data: hello, encoding: .utf8)!) // "Hello world!"
```

And then get a range of data

```
let rangeOfWorld = Data(hello[6...11])
print(String(data: rangeOfWorld, encoding: .utf8)!) // "world!"
```

Comment: hi vadian, thanks for your response. I'm a little confused can you show it in my code as above on how collection type can be performed? :)

Comment: What is `tb1.flatMap{UInt8(String($0)` supposed to do?

Comment: Hi thanks now I got it :) well textbox.text returns a string which is say "12" but I will have to convert it to two UInt8 numbers so when I use the above flatmap I get [1,2] and its a UInt8. Hope that helps

Comment: I understand. I tried it with letters and of course it didn't work.

Comment: yes I think it wont work with letters thats why I put my textbox text keypad to numbers :)